# Delete button show only user which book event and Admin in fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I'm making event booking system using fullCalendar.js with the backhand of codeigniter, first there is 2 role user and Admin, User can book the event and delete the event but i want to show delete button only Admin and user which book the event. So can anyone please tell me how this can be possible.The delete button in modal box and show on eventClick in Calendar.My Html and javascript are

```
<div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Event Details</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="eventID"/>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteButton">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

//----------------------Javascript-------------------------------

```
$('#deleteButton').on('click', function(){
       // delete button
       doDelete();
   });
function doDelete(){
        $("#calendarModal").modal('hide');
       var eventID = $('#eventID').val();
       var baseUrl = document.location.origin;
       $.ajax({
           url: baseUrl+'/mrbs/api/post_api',// 
           data: 'action=delete&id='+eventID,
           type: "POST",
       });
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');  
   }
```

Thanks in advance ........:)

Comment: Show tables events and users

Comment: are you talking about SQL table??

Comment: @codexxx yess table stracture for booking and users

Comment: For meeting :-  https://prnt.sc/gnuae4

Comment: for user:-https://prnt.sc/gnuav2

Comment: Is your delete button in modal popup

Comment: Yes delete button in modal popup which is generate as event is displayed in calendar

Answer (score 0):

You should probably control display of the delete button on the server-side, not in Javascript on the client.  That means using Codeigniter when rendering the modal, so for example:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <?php if ( ... test if user is admin ... ) { ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteButton">Delete</button>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

You should also confirm in your controller method (`/mrbs/api/post_api`) that the user is an admin before actually doing the delete.

**UPDATE**

If you want to display only events created by the current user, you should handle that on your server-side event source.  You have not posted your Fullcalendar code, but you must have something like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // ... code
    events: "some/path/to/server-side-json",
 });
```

In your `some/path/to/server-side-json` controller method, check the user id of the user making this query, and only return events created by that user.

Comment: But how to send u-id (user id which book the event) from ajax ??

Comment: Do you mean you want to send user id from your event source?  Event source can include anything, but why do you want to do that?  Maybe you want to only **retrieve** events for the current user?  If so you need to send user ID **to** your event source back end, right?

Comment: no i want to show the user which event you booked and you can edit or delete

Comment: and how to check the event which display in calendar is booked by the user which is currently login or another booked this event ?

Comment: Actually i need different help, i'm able to render event on calendar and add a eventClick action on event details, when click on booked event it show a model popup which has details about events and delete button but i tried if(bookid==sessionid) but doesn't hide delete button

Comment: Where does the modal HTML come from? If you are sending it from the server, on eventClick, it is server-generated and you can use Codeigniter to check logged in user and include delete button or not (exactly as I describe in my answer).